# New [tag] questions for [date] email script stuck?

Tags: bug, email

I'm getting the same email again and again from Android enthusiasts today, I think there's a looping script somewhere in your system.

The email is:

```
1 new question in samsung-gt-i9000 filter on stackexchange.com

Hide / Add / Replace dock icons on home screen

I have Samsung galaxy Y and I do have 2 questions about dock settings on home screen. Is it possible to Hide / Modify dock on home screen? Is it possible to make it toggle on touch the home screen? …
Tagged: applications samsung-galaxy-s settings samsung   by Dhaval on android.stackexchange.com
Unsubscribe from this filter or change your email preferences by visiting your filter subscriptions page on stackexchange.com.

Questions? Comments? Let us know on our feedback site. If you no longer want to receive mail from Stack Exchange, unsubscribe from all stackexchange.com emails. 

Stack Exchange, Inc. One Exchange Plaza, 26th Floor, NY NY 10006 <3
```

Could you please check as I wouldn't want to unsubscribe from any tags, but don't really care for the extra notifications on my devices.

Comment: Same here on StackOverflow for me. I've got 5 mails about 6 new [silverlight-5.0] questions.

Comment: The mails are 15 minutes apart in the beginning and the last two only 3 minutes apart, if it helps.