# Multiple copies of emails from Stack Exchange (Arqade)

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New [tag] questions for [date] email script stuck?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151642/new-tag-questions-for-date-email-script-stuck)

I just received 6 identical emails of the "New  questions for Oct 17 - Stack Exchange" variety.

Bug?

If it helps, they were for the Arqade site.

**EDIT**: Looks like a broader problem than just Arqade. Users in SO and Android Enthusiasts are reporting the same issue.

Comment: Same problem with the android enthusiasts. I think it is for every SE site

Comment: I'm on 8 so far from SO. @MatthewD - can we upgrade your question to be for multiple sites?

Comment: @PreetSangha: I've edited the question... but the reason I posted here instead of the Arqade meta is because I suspected the issue was with Stack Exchange.